# Can you cast Squee, the Immortal when it is exiled with a bomat courier?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can you cast [Squee](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=squee%2C%20the%20immortal) when it is exiled faced down with [Bomat Courier](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=417772) or can you NOT cast a face-down exiled card?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot cast a Squee the Immortal while it is exiled with Bomat Courier. Cards that are exiled face down have no characteristics, so the card does not have Squee's ability that allows you to cast it (see [rule 406.3](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Exile)).